# SQL command to show 0 if doesn't exist in the join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem in a SQL command.

I have a table with questions, other with the possible answers to that questions and other with the replies from the users.

Imagine the following example:

**Question 1**: Who will win semi-final? 
**Aswners**: A) Portugal B) Spain
**Replies**: 10 people voted B) Spain, 0 people voted A) Portugal

```
SELECT a.answer, COUNT(r.id) as total
FROM replies r
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.id = r.id_answer
LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.id = a.id_question
WHERE q.id = 1
GROUP BY r.id_answer
```

My point is to get from the
`SELECT` the result:
**Spain 10

Portugal 0**

But i can't, i don't know how to do it, because the way i did, i always get only the result from the asnwers with replies on the replies table. Like this:
**Spain 10**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to start with your questions, and `LEFT JOIN` the replies.

```
SELECT a.answer, COUNT(r.id_answer) AS total
FROM questions q
JOIN answers a ON ( a.id_question = q.id )
LEFT JOIN replies r ON ( r.id_answer = a.id )
WHERE q.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id, a.answer
```

With your current query you don't even need the `question`:

```
SELECT a.answer, COUNT(r.id_answer) AS total
FROM answers a
LEFT JOIN replies r ON ( r.id_answer = a.id )
WHERE a.id_question = 1
GROUP BY a.id, a.answer
```

[See this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b50a/2) for your second query on SQL Fiddle, that returns:

```
ANSWER      TOTAL
Spain       10
Portugal    0
```

Comment: @costa : What didn't work? I meant what were you expecting and what you didn't get? Please tell that so that Peter can help you solving your problem.

Comment: I was expecting a result like "Spain 10, Portugal 0" but i only get "Spain 10" because on the question with the ID = 1 only exists replies to the Spain option

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example using SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.answer, COUNT(r.id) as total
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN answers a ON a.id_question  = q.id
LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.id_answer = a.id
WHERE q.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Use Left join instead of inner join.

**Edit** : Join updated.

Comment: I edited my post, i'm already using LEFT JOIN. I forget to add the probably focus of the problem, which it is the WHERE clause with the q.id = 1

Comment: ok let me update the answer as you have updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

your query should be this way -

```
SELECT a.answer, COUNT(r.id) as total 
FROM questions q 
INNER JOIN JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id_question
LEFT JOIN REPLIES r ON a.id = r.id_answer
WHERE
q.id=1
GROUP BY 
a.answer
```

whats important here is  `count(r.id)` to get  `Portugal 0`